# Disable line comments compass not working

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to disable line comments in my compass config.rb file but I still keep getting the line references to the scss file in my normal css file.

```
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
line_comments = false
```

I've restarted compass. Deleted my cache folder and my css file after saving my .scss. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My config.rb file was being ignored. Fixed it by going into the folder with commandline and typing `compass watch` from within the folder.

Still puzzles my because I have other projects in my WAMP folder and I just use compass watch [project] for those and the `config.rb` file for those does not get ignored.

Comment: make sure that compass watch is not running. If so, stop it and restart it after you have made changes to your config.rb file

Answer (score -2):

Even with output style "compressed", I have not been able to remove multi-line comments, and the sass/scss documentation also suggests that they are not removed (only single-line comments with "//" are removed).

My solution was to simply apply a Perl one-liner to manually remove comments from a .css file, after sass has generated its final output:

```
sass -fCE utf-8 -t compressed application.sass application.css
perl -pi -e'BEGIN{$/=undef}s#/\*.*?\*/##gs' application.css
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```
compass_config do |config|
  config.sass_options = { :line_comments => false }
end
```

Comment: @cimmanon what? this is the only way that worked for me... none of the ones above did.